# Rails Manual SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following relationship

`Foo` has_many `Bar`

Then i have the `Foo` model however the `Bar` is just a `String` which is an `id`.
I could create a `Bar` model consisting only the `String id`, but i want to know if is possible and how to make `Foo` query all `Bars` and store it inside as a `list` in the `Foo` model.

If i have to use SQL it is fine.

Another alternative is to remove the `Bar` table and then put it as a field in the `Foo` table however this would require to serialize and would difficult and make SQL search inefficient guess.

The schema is the follwing

`Foo` has_many `Foo_Bars` and
`Bar` has_many `Bar_Foos`

The reason for not been `Foo` has_and_belongs_to_many `Bar` is because the add information of a single `Foo` or a single `Bar` would be a never ending chain, think this as a bipartite graph such as `Foo` and `Bar` are a disjoint set.

The database is shared with another application i am using rails as a visual interface to manage the data.

My question is do i really need a `Foo_Bars` model ?

Comment: Will you ever have a random Bar that you will need to lookup which Foo it belongs to? Can a Bar belong to more than one Foo? If so, are you ever going to need to search for all of the Foo's having a specific Bar? Depending on what, exactly, Foo and Bar represent and their real-life relation, there are many ways this could go. Everything from serialized attributes in Foo to a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with a join table. More info, please.

Comment: yes this was supose to be a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship but because in most scenarios the Foo entity does not need to lookup entire Bar information a the Bar.id is enough to set up the relationship. Also i forget to mention to get information of Bar is costly thats why i decided only the Bar.id is enough which cames with the Foo entity. There is a another table Bar which contains full information.

Comment: If you only want to pull the id, you can leave it as a 'Foo has_many Bars' relation and use 'foo.bars.all :select => :id'. That will create SQL equivalent to: 'select id from bars where bars.foo_id = #{foo.id}'. As long as the foreign key bars.foo_id is indexed, it should be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you'll have to create a bar model. Rails default primary id is an integer, not a string. You seem to want to list all Bars that 'belong_to' a Foo. So your migration will look like this:

> rails g model bar foo_id:integer

Now inside /models/bar.rb:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Your models/foo.rb:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end
```

create some Bar records with foo foreign ids, and you can now query all the bars that belong to foo by this:

```
foo = Foo.find id
foo.bars
```

or from Bar:

```
Bar.where(:foo_id => id)
```

Read and practice this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this method in Foo model

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :barlist

  ...

  def store_barlist
    update_attributes(:barlist => self.bars.map {|bar| bar.string_id })
  end
end
```

To call this in controller, you'd have to do something like this.

```rb
def some_controller_action
  @foo = Foo.find(1)
  @foo.store_barlist
end
```